# You can't specify target table 'A' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

This is my request

```
> DELETE FROM A WHERE id in (    Select
> id From A    Left Join B on A.id=B.id 
> Where B.id is null )
```

When I execute this I have this error

> You can't specify target table 'A' for
>   update in FROM clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Delete: can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could do it like this instead?

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT B.id FROM B);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete all records from table A that don't have a matching id in table B?

How about this:

```
DELETE
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from B where A.id = B.id);
```

Comment: OK, nice to know. I thought you're not allowed to mention the outer tables at all in nested selects...

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM B
    WHERE content_id = B.content_id
)
```